# Discord.JS Trying to send a message to a user

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to send a DM to a user by their ID. My code is:

```js
client.users.fetch('ID').send('Message')
```

The error I get when this code runs:

```
client.users.fetch('ID').send('Message')
                         ^

TypeError: client.users.fetch(...).send is not a function
    at Client.<anonymous> (C:\Users\your user name\Desktop\dokumentumok\Guardian\main.js:120:55)
    at Client.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\your user name\Desktop\dokumentumok\Guardian\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\your user name\Desktop\dokumentumok\Guardian\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\your user name\Desktop\dokumentumok\Guardian\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:386:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\your user name\Desktop\dokumentumok\Guardian\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:435:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\your user name\Desktop\dokumentumok\Guardian\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:293:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\your user name\Desktop\dokumentumok\Guardian\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:120:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:311:20)
    at Receiver.receiverOnMessage (C:\Users\your user name\Desktop\dokumentumok\Guardian\node_modules\ws\lib\websocket.js:801:20)
77
```

(This is not the exact error message, I replaced my id with ID and the message with Message. This is my first question here.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Client.users.fetch does not return a user, it returns a promise of a User, but it takes time to resolve.  You need to handle the asynchronous execution using a `.then` or `async/await`.

```
client.users.fetch('ID').then(user => user.send('Message'));
```